# Dynamic file path in assets reverse routing

Tags: java, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am trying to use reverse routing to access static Assets using:

```
@routes.Assets.at("path", "file")
```

However I would like to define file as dynamic part as well like:

```
@for(c <- models.WebContent.find.all) {
  <img src="@routes.Assets.at("/contentfiles/useruploads", "@c.picture1")">
}
```

Statement above however results in HTML code:

```
   <img src="/contentfiles/userupload/@c.picture1">
```

Where you can see dynamic part @c.picture1 is not interpreted as dynamic filename but is parsed as raw text resulting in broken link. What I am expecting is that both dynamic parts are interpreted as dynamic resulting in eg.:

```
<img src="/contentfiles/userupload/1776446515.jpg">
```

How to define it so both dynamic statements are parsed as dynamic?
PS: I have tried to escape it as @@c.picture or $@c.picture with no luck

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using variables as a function argument use it w/out `@` char and also not within quotes, otherwise as you can is it's used as a... String

```
<img src="@routes.Assets.at("/contentfiles/useruploads", c.picture1)">
```

The same as in condition:

```
Use:
@if(foo==bar){...}

NOT
@if(@foo==@bar){...}
```

Comment: Thank you. I literally tried everything even without @ char but I didn't think about removing quotes.